# Working with frames in webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-controls

I am using `<webbrowser>.Document.Window.Frames` to get frames.
My `<WebBrowser>` having 2 frames.My only problem is ,I seem one at index 0, but not 1.

Any help?

```
HtmlWindow wf = wb.Document.Window.Frames[1]; 
string s = wf.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
```

and view source

```
    <frameset rows="0,*" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0"> 
    <frame name="entrustTruePassAppletFrame" src="EntrustTruePassApplet.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" noresize>
   <!-- It is mandatory for the frame where the user interaction happens to have the name  defined in the Configuration as appletHtmlGuiTarget--> 
<frame name="entrustTruePassGuiFrame" src="AuthenticateUserInputRoamingEPF.html"> </frameset>
```

Comment: you are askign the source code of webpage?

Comment: Yes, just the relevant piece where you declare your frames

Comment: This is the code in .net app:

Comment: HtmlWindow wf = wb.Document.Window.Frames[1];
                string s = wf.Document.Body.OuterHtml; and view source <frameset rows="0,*" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
        <frame name="entrustTruePassAppletFrame" src="EntrustTruePassApplet.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" noresize>
        <!-- It is mandatory for the frame where the user interaction happens to have
        the name defined in the Configuration as appletHtmlGuiTarget-->
        <frame name="entrustTruePassGuiFrame" src="AuthenticateUserInputRoamingEPF.html">
    </frameset>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting frames using their name instead of index:

```
wb.Document.Window.Frames["entrustTruePassAppletFrame"];
```

Actually I think using index is not good at all, because if at a later time you add/remove a single frame it ruins all your work as the indexes changes.