# C# Unable to login with WebBrowser

Tags: c#, authentication, webbrowser-control

I am newbie to C#. I need help to be able to login the webpage and read some data.

After googling, I tried to find below code and other resources but in all cases, I can only get the html source of the login page but not other pages source data.

1. I need to traverse to the homepage first.
2. Then, I need to traverse
   to "Port Status" and read some useful data. To inform data is stored in the
   frames. How can I read data from the frames ?

### Adding more info

1) view-source:http://192.168.0.239/homepage.html, which calls script as shown below

getSubTree('Management');

2) The above call hits the content in java script file (http://192.168.0.239/frame.js)

```
    case "Management":
       str += OneNodeLink("lv1", "Switch Information", "/iss/specific/sysInfo.html?Gambit="+GAMBIT);
       str += OneNodeLink("lv1", "Port Status", "/iss/specific/port_settings.html?Gambit="+GAMBIT);
```

document.getElementById("treeFrame").innerHTML = str;

3) The above code executes this file "view-source:http://192.168.0.239/iss/specific/port_settings.html?Gambit=pisfgagehesfhjikojngqcabdfkjeeffmpkhfckm" and gets "Port Status"

My requirement is to read the "Port Status" received which is from the frames data. Hope I am able to make it clear. Let me know if you need more info to help.

Link has screenshots and html source files : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oml3tk75tf1lu5c/AADuGtbZci3gnyOQ2AE8IYwua?dl=0

Thanks a lot in advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WebBrowserWithoutAForm
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool completed = false;
        private static WebBrowser wb;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);

            string postData = string.Format("LoginPassword={0}&login=Login", "password");
            ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
            wb.Navigate("http://192.168.0.239", "", enc.GetBytes(postData), "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");            

            //wb.Navigate("http://192.168.0.239");

            while (!completed)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            Console.Write("\n\nDone with it!\n\n");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
            completed = true;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

           //*******HERE I NEED TO TRAVERSE TO THE HOME PAGE AND GET ITS SOURCE ******
            wb.Navigate("http://192.168.0.239/homepage.html");

            Console.WriteLine(wb.DocumentText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `selenium` - [my sample code of using Selenium to login facebook](https://github.com/Rarve/Circle.Life.Test)

I'm not gonna code for you but you could copy some part of my code though.

Answer (score 0):

For the login page, I would do a GetElementById on the input for the login, and then set the value attribute. Then for the login button, if it's actually a button, I would trigger the click() event, otherwise if it is a form, then I would do a submit.

For port Status, you would again need to know the html of the home page and do a GetElementById on it and then trigger a click() event.

To put some code to these words it would look something like this:

```
        var portStatus = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("portStatus");
        portStatus.InvokeMember("click");

        //this should give you access to DOM of the first frame on the page.
        //if you have more than 1 then you will need to know which one.
        var frameDoc= this.webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document;           
        //or
        var frameDoc= this.webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["iframeid"].Document;;

        var login = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Login");
        login.SetAttribute("Value", "password");

        var loginButton = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("LoginButton");
        loginButton.InvokeMember("click");

        //or if the login button is a form then submit the form
        HtmlElement form = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("FormID");
        if (form != null)
            form.InvokeMember("submit");
```

Since you didn't provide the HTML of the homepage, The Id's used here would have to be replaced by the actual Ids of the page. And you would replace "password" with whatever your actual password is here.

I hope this helps, if you need some explanation let me know.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808219/working-with-frames-in-webbrowser-control) for working with frames

Comment: Thanks for your comment but sorry I can't really make use of it.  I can try "this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("portStatus")" as there is no such to retrieve. Please check the additional info added to my post which might help you to help me

Comment: The source file you posted for the homepage does not include the main content's Iframe. Everything we need is inside of that.If you can post that, I may be able to help.

Comment: Also, If you use google chrome, your best bet it to use the developer tools to inspect the elements in question. The developer tools will let you click on stuff visually in the page and show you the code for it.  Actually you can do this with pretty much any web browser, though the tools work slightly differently in each one.